# Specific separator can separate the data frame

Tags: r

I try to execute this command

```
df2 <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(setNames(strsplit(df$col1, "---", fixed = TRUE), df$id))[2:1]))
```

However I receive this error:

> ```
> Error in table(stack(setNames(strsplit(df$col1,  : 
>   attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements
> ```

Any idea why this error happaned? Unfortunately I can't provide a reproducable example with this code because I can't find what caused this error.

What makes this command is that it make 0 and 1 values which separate by ---.

Example input:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2), col1 = c("text---here","text---there"))
```

expected output

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c(1,1), here = c(1,0), there = c(0,1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the task in question is complex, it is worth splitting it into chunks. Try this:

```
x = data.frame(id = c(1,2), col1 = c("text---here","text---there")); x$col1 = as.vector(x$col1)
Split = strsplit(as.vector(x$col1), split = "---")
levels = unique(unlist(Split))
x = cbind(x, matrix(ncol = length(levels), nrow = nrow(x)))
for(i in 1:length(levels))
{
  x[,ncol(x)-length(levels)+i] <- sapply(Split, function(x) max(x == levels[i]))
}
colnames(x) <- c("id", "col1", levels)
x
# id         col1 text here there
# 1  1  text---here    1    1     0
# 2  2 text---there    1    0     1
```

Comment: thank you, I need to have as column names the text which is insed the split. Please check the expected output example I provided

Comment: Dear Heln, I have added a line to include the columns names. I have also replaced grepl for an exact matching on the splitted vector: as some levels are contained in the others (for example, "here" is contained in "there"), the resulting data.frame was not entirely correct.